# make AppEngine static_dir continue to the next handler if a file is not found

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My àpp.yaml handlers currently look like this

```
handlers:
- url: /api/.*
  script: _go_app

- url: /
  static_dir: ../frontend/build

- url: .*
  static_files: ../frontend/build/index.html
  upload: ../frontend/build/index.html
```

I'd like it tou route any requests that match a file in `../frontend/build`to that file, and all other requests to `../frontend/build/index.html`, but currently, the `/` url for the  `static_dir` catches everything, and returns a 404 if the file doesn't exist. If possible, I'd prefer not to manually add every file name in my build directory to the yaml file for routing. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
- url: /frontend/build/(.*\.(html|gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: frontend/build/\1
  upload: frontend/build/.*\.(html|gif|png|jpg)$

- url: .*
  static_files: frontend/build/index.html
  upload: frontend/build/index.html
```

Comment: Thx that at least reduces the times I have to update app.yaml to when I add new types of files

Comment: You can add other extensions, too.  txt|pdf|xml|jpeg